# Maven - Reactors (Aggregation)

Tags: maven

I have a maven project with a following directory structure:

```
trunk
|    pom.xml
|    coreutils
|            |    pom.xml
|            |    src
|    budgetCap
|            |    pom.xml
|            |    src
```

The content of trunk/pom.xml is :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0              
hxttp://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>Ant2Maven</groupId>
<artifactId>parent</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>

<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>Parent Pom</name>

<modules>

    <module>coreutils</module>
    <module>budgetCap</module>

</modules>
```

In this structure, "budgetCap" is dependent on "coreutils",i.e. pom.xml of "budgetCap" contains a dependency of "coreutils"

Now I have two methods to build this project

**First Method**
Aggregation using Reactor

I will be inside **trunk**

So first of all I do mvn clean

```
shakim:trunk shakim.md$ mvn clean
```

Maven deletes the target folder of the two module in this order:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] coreutils
[INFO] budgetCap Maven Webapp
[INFO] Parent Pom
```

Now when i do mvn install

```
shakim:trunk shakim.md$ mvn install
```

Maven starts building modules in the following order:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] coreutils
[INFO] budgetCap Maven Webapp
[INFO] Parent Pom
```

In the given order, **coreutils** gets installed in the local repository successfully.
But **budgetCap** fails at the compilation giving an error that **maven is unable to locate a class which was supposed to be produced by coreutils**

the error message is as follows:

```
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building budgetCap Maven Webapp 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ budgetCap ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 4 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ budgetCap ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 65 source files to /Users/shakim.md/shakim/maven/ops/adq_services/trunk/budgetCap/target/classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] COMPILATION WARNING : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING]/Users/shakim.md/shakim/maven/ops/adq_services/trunk/budgetCap/src/main/java/com/adiquity/budgetCap/core/SingletonAggregator.java: /Users/shakim.md/shakim/maven/ops/adq_services/trunk/budgetCap/src/main/java/com/adiquity/budgetCap/core/SingletonAggregator.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
[WARNING]/Users/shakim.md/shakim/maven/ops/adq_services/trunk/budgetCap/src/main/java/com/adiquity/budgetCap/core/SingletonAggregator.java: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[INFO] 2 warnings 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /Users/shakim.md/shakim/maven/ops/adq_services/trunk/budgetCap/src/main/java/com/adiquity/budgetCap/core/BudgetCapServer.java:[41,34] package com.adiquity.request.utils does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/shakim.md/shakim/maven/ops/adq_services/trunk/budgetCap/src/main/java/com/adiquity/budgetCap/utils/Utils.java:[9,34] package com.adiquity.request.utils does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/shakim.md/shakim/maven/ops/adq_services/trunk/budgetCap/src/main/java/com/adiquity/budgetCap/log/data/parser/ConversionParser.java:[16,34] package com.adiquity.request.utils does not exist
```

Briefly speaking this package **package com.adiquity.request.utils** is actually present in **coreutils**, which this module **budgetCap** must have located successfully, but it is not.

**Second Method**

Go inside **coreutils** and do a

```
shakim:coreutils shakim.md$ mvn clean install
```

Go inside **budgetCap** and do a

```
shakim:budgetCap shakim.md$ mvn clean install
```

budgetCap compiles successfully without reporting any kind of error.

My question is that I want to use **Reactors** in Maven and I am unable to figure out why the build fails on using 1st method whereas 2nd method of building completes smoothly??

I am not sure how to use reactors, do we need to include anything in **pom of coreutils and budgetCap** signifying that **pom of trunk** is the parent.

Note: I don't want to use inheritance in this project

Comment: Please show the error message you got...

Comment: edited......please look again........

Comment: The best to such issues to clean the local repository and just make a `mvn clean package` this should work without any issue. Do you have the project somewhere where we can take a look?

Comment: Thanks for help!. I cannot share this project. But if I clean my local repository and do a "mvn clean package" then don't you think I surely be getting error, as "first project will not be there in local repository", so from where will "2nd project resolve its dependencies"??

Comment: No this will be resolved from the maven-reactor during the build by Maven. If this works we are sure the structure and dependencies are correctly configured.

Comment: Ok... "mvn clean compile" works,....both modules gets compiled successfully....but on doing "mvn clean package" or "mvn clean install"....second module fails at compilation only....what could be the reason for this???

Comment: Ah...that sounds like your dependencies between the modules are not correct.Do you have the project somewhere available ? (GitHub ?)

Comment: I have uploaded this project in github. Please look at this https://github.com/codefor6768/hopethisworks/

Comment: Hey thanks..........I think I found the problem, **artifactId** and **name of the jar** with which the given artifact was packaged was not same. Making it same fixed the problem.

Comment: Exactly what i expected....